# QTextEdit as a child node for QTreeWidgetItem?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextedit, qtreewidget

Is it possible to add a QTextEdit as a child in QTreeWidget?

Here is my code we can create a QTreeWidget and add the columns:

```
self.treetext = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
        self.treetext.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("treetext"))
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.treetext)
        self.treetext.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 261, 241))
        item_0 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treetext)
        item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_0 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.treetext)
        item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
        item_1 = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(item_0)
```

and add new items as child:

```
self.treetext.headerItem().setText(0, _translate("Form", "Model List", None))
        __sortingEnabled = self.treetext.isSortingEnabled()
        self.treetext.setSortingEnabled(False)
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(0).setText(0, _translate("Form", "Model 1", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(0).child(0).setText(0, _translate("Form", "New Subitem", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(0).child(1).setText(0, _translate("Form", "New Item", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(0).child(2).setText(0, _translate("Form", "New Item", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(0).child(3).setText(0, _translate("Form", "New Item", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(1).setText(0, _translate("Form", "Model 2", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(1).child(0).setText(0, _translate("Form", "New Subitem", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(1).child(1).setText(0, _translate("Form", "New Item", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(1).child(2).setText(0, _translate("Form", "New Item", None))
        self.treetext.topLevelItem(1).child(3).setText(0, _translate("Form", "New Item", None))
        self.treetext.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
```

Can Create a new QTextEdit with other example:

```
self.groupBox = QtGui.QTextEdit(self.dockWidgetContents_2)
self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.groupBox)
```

But can we put QTextEdit as a new child for QTreeWidgetItem?

Comment: Yes that should be possible. Have you tried? Where is the problem?

Comment: Did the solution I proposed work for you?  Or did you use something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a widget on any item in the tree using [`setItemWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget)

```
self.treetext.setItemWidget(item_1, 0, QTextEdit(self))
```

If your tree widget items are editable, you can also just tell Qt to open a persistent editor (by default, `QTreeWidgetItems` use a `QLineEdit` for editing, but you can override that behavior with a `QItemDelegate` if you want) using [`openPersistentEditor()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtreewidget.html#openPersistentEditor)

```
self.treetext.openPersistentEditor(item_1, 0)
```